# What methods - inspired by Haavelmo’s Structural Econometrics - can show that a partial equilibrium model is unreliable?

Tags: macroeconomics, econometrics, general-equilibrium, dsge

According to Spanos 2014 [Revisiting Haavelmo's Structural econometrics: Bridging the gap between theory and data](https://secure.hosting.vt.edu/www.econ.vt.edu/directory/spanos/spanos9.pdf) Dynamic Stochastic General Equilibrium models are statistically inadequate, in such an order of magnitude as to render them useless.

> The most serious problem with DSGE models is that they are often statistically inadequate. Advocates of DSGE modeling, however, have
>   put forward a number of arguments to explain away the unreliability of
>   their evidence, such as ‘the price one has to pay for rigorous and
>   policy-relevant theoretical models’ (Lucas, 1980, p. 696), or simply
>   inevitable: “The models constructed within this theoretical framework
>   are necessarily highly abstract. Consequently, they are necessarily
>   false, and statistical hypothesis testing will reject them. This does
>   not imply, however, that nothing can be learned from such quantitative
>   theoretical exercises.” (Prescott, 1986, p. 10)

Part of my research involves using a partial equilibrium models to simulate a particular segment of an economy.

Considering the above, what methods would you start with to show that a given equilibrium model is statistically unreliable?

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two big ways.

1. Formal tests of model fit: If you are using SMM, GMM or indirect influence check out the [J-stat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_method_of_moments#J-test). If you are using maximum likelihood you want a [likelihood ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test). [Bayesian model testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_factor) is similar to likelihood ratios, but more complicated. Many of the DSGE models were rejected on these bases (you can see Sargent discussing it briefly in [this interview](https://files.nyu.edu/ts43/public/research/SargentinterviewMD.pdf)). These tests are all very similar.
2. Out of sample performance: Estimate the model, then use it to predict out of sample data. This is a tough test, but it is super useful. They aren't so common in economics, but statisticians use them a lot (often times they leave out part of the data and try the model out there). You probably want your model to pass a formal test in sample before you do an out of sample test.

All these tests rely on the same, extremely basic, intuition: If the model is good then it should fit the data well. If the model does not fit the data well it is probably not good.